# android emulator restarts itself (ADT)

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator

When i invoke a function which is described below, android emulator restarts from beginning.

The function is like that

```
int index = 0;
 Position myPostion;
 Position destPosition = roadInstruction.getInstructionAt(index).getEndAddr();

 while(index<roadInstruction.getNumInstruction())
 {  
    myPostion = getMyPosition();

    while(!hasArrivedToDestination(myPostion, destPosition ))
    {
        myPostion = getMyPosition();

    }
    ++index;
}
```

What is the reason? 
It maybe because of the inner while loop, but i am not sure.

Comment: Please go back and accept some of the answers to your previous questions. See this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask.

Comment: Is the emulator literally restarting, or is it just your application running in the emulator that restarts?

Comment: emulator restarted not application and also emulator gives Emulator] emulator: ERROR: unexpected qemud char. channel close error

Comment: Increase you ram and heap size